# Voting to Leave open, then still be able to vote for close?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

This question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194028/export-image-as-eps-but-pi-symbol-changes-in-matlab was in my `Close Review` queue. I voted to leave open.

The post mentioned is just an example, I do not refer to the content of that post at all.

[image]

After some time, there were 2 close votes visible on the post

[image]

I was curious if I could still vote for close, although the question was already in the queue and I voted as mentioned.

The answer is: Yes, it is possible to vote for close! I did that, but retracted it afterwards.

Why is is this possible? As a chance to think again about a previous `Leave open` vote? 
;-)

This question is somehow related to [What is the difference between these two kinds of close votes?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4464/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-kinds-of-close-votes), but is not a duplicate, in my point of view.

[image]

[image]

I added some screen shots to show the proceedings...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that people can change their minds, this isn't a problem (in the same way that you *can* retract a close vote).

There isn't a good reason to disallow close votes - given that edits or additional comments may push the question to something that you'd rather close (for example).

Comment: I think, the edit/comment aspect is crucial: It can change the meaning of a question definitely!

Comment: Well, on the other hand: I can retract a `close vote` on the `close` link, but I can not retract a `Leave open` or `Recommend deletion` inside the review queues... This is a little bit schizophrenic, in my point of view